# SQL Server CTE Error in Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I had a stored procedure that was slow (and was missing new data), I need to make it faster, so I used a CTE this time (first time using).

The old one was

```
Declare @Cod_Func as int;
set @Cod_Func = 10310  

BEGIN
    SELECT
        D.Cod_Regional,  
        D.Nom_Regional + ' (' + CAST(COUNT(A.ID_Chegada) as varchar) + ')' as Nom_Regional  
    FROM   
        APS_CHEGADA A (NOLOCK)  
    INNER JOIN   
        APS_AcessoFilial B (NOLOCK) ON A.Cod_Regional = B.Cod_Regional 
                                    AND A.Cod_Filial = B.Cod_Filial 
                                    AND B.flg_situacao = 1  
    INNER JOIN  
        COR_Filial C (NOLOCK) ON A.Cod_Regional = C.Cod_Regional 
                              AND A.Cod_Filial = C.Cod_Filial  
    INNER JOIN  
        COR_Regional D (NOLOCK) ON C.Cod_RegionalAtual = D.Cod_Regional  
    WHERE   
        A.ID_ChegadaStatus = 2 
        AND B.Cod_Func = @Cod_Func  
        AND A.FLG_SITUACAO = 1
    GROUP BY   
        D.Cod_Regional, D.Nom_Regional 
End;
```

And the new one is:

```
BEGIN  
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    WITH tblRegionais AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            [R].COD_Regional,
            [F].COD_Regional AS [COD_RegionalReal],
            [R].Nom_Regional
        FROM
            COR_Regional [R] WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN
            COR_FILIAL [F] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [R].COD_REGIONAL = [F].COD_RegionalAtual
        INNER JOIN
            APS_AcessoFilial [AF] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [F].COD_Regional = [AF].COD_Regional
                                               AND [F].COD_Filial = [AF].COD_Filial
        WHERE
            [F].FLG_SituacaoRegistro = 1
            AND [AF].FLG_Situacao = 1
            AND [AF].COD_Func = @COD_Func
    ),
    tblChegadas AS
    ( 
        SELECT
            [R].COD_Regional,
            COUNT([C].ID_Chegada) AS [QTD_Chegada]
        FROM
            tblRegionais [R]
        INNER JOIN
            APS_Chegada [C] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [R].COD_RegionalReal = [C].COD_Regional
        WHERE
            [C].ID_ChegadaStatus = 2
        GROUP BY
            [R].COD_Regional
    ),
    tblSaida AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            [R].COD_Regional,
            RTRIM([R].Nom_Regional) + ' (' + CAST([C].QTD_Chegada AS VARCHAR(30)) + ')' AS [NOM_Regional]
        FROM
            tblRegionais [R]
        INNER JOIN
            tblChegadas [C] ON [R].COD_Regional = [C].COD_Regional
    )
    SELECT 
        [S].COD_Regional,
        [S].NOM_Regional
    FROM
        tblSaida [S];       
END
```

The problem is the new one is four times slower now, and the result is not in a group like the last one, but I'm using the group by in "tblChegada".

I'm also adding the two images with the time of executing

[image: NEW ONE - VERY SLOW]

[image: OLD ONE]

Comment: What is your question exactly? It is regarding the execution time or the grouping?

Comment: CTEs are a convenience for syntax, or they offer new functionality (recursive CTEs).  They should not have an impact on performance, however in SQL Server.

Comment: Both,but the one i really wanna know its why its not grouping correctly,this is the bigger problem,the execution time i will continue to try to improve with small changes.

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: I don't think the CTE is going to make things faster, and it might make things slower.  Look at the Query Plans in SQL Management studio and see how you can improve the query from there.

Comment: The problem is probably in the count,the old one got in Regional I 772 values,but in my new it got 8549,cleary wrong.

Comment: In Execution plan 91% is usage of Clustered Index Scan  (APS_Chegada).PKS_APS_Chegada [C]

Comment: I really want to know why my group by is not working,it was suppose to group the cod_regional and count the ID_Chegada,in the new one i need to receive 3 rows ,but i'm getting 14

Comment: your missing the point of a common table expression and I woudln't use it here.  It shouldn't make things faster and often as @DanielGimenez mentions it actually makes things slower because we tend to write less optimized queries when we just plaster cte's every where.  cte is useful when you want a multi stepped operation.  Such as return all duplicate rows.  First cte finds duplicate values then query it to get original rows.  In the case above I don't see any benefit to a cte and your performance is likely tanked because your 1 query is now 3 with potentially more data as well.

Comment: @Vinicius Nascimento Why do you care about number of records returned? By definition when you use `NOLOCK` means you do not care.

Answer (score -1):

I think, that `tblChegadas` returns 3 records but `tblRegionais` returns more than 3 records (`DISTINCT` includes `COR_FILIAL.COD_Regional`).

After you did `GROUP BY [R].COD_Regional`, you did `INNER JOIN` in `tblSaida`, so `tblSaida` returns more records than 3 because `tblRegionais` returns more than 3 records.